# Create a loop to scan the values of array and match it with the class name of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

I'm trying to create a multiple filter which displays related elements upon clicking the checkbox. When a green check box is checked, it should display green div and when green and red checkbox are clicked, it should display div with green and red class else should display none. I have stored  checkbox class in an array once the checkbox is clicked.

[FE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foBbC.png)

[CONSOLE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B69ap.png)

```js
<script>
        var classname = [];
        $( function () {

            $( '.check' ).change( function () {
                if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
                    // $( '.main div' ).css( 'display', 'none' );

                    classname.push( ( this ).className );
                    console.log( classname );

                }
                if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) == false ) {
                    classname.pop( ( this ).className );
                };
            } );
        } );
        $( '#clear' ).on( 'click', () => {
            $( '.check' ).prop( 'checked', false );
            classname.length = 0;
        } );

    </script>
```

```html
 <div class="container grid">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="green  check">Green
                    <input type="checkbox" class="blue check">Blue
                    <input type="checkbox" class="red check">Red
                    <input type="checkbox" class="yellow check">Yellow
                    <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clear">
                </div>
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="green yellow">Green Yellow</div>
                    <div class="blue red"></div>
                    <div class="yellow"></div>
                    <div class="blue"></div>
                    <div class="green"></div>
                    <div class="green red">Green Red</div>
                    <div class="red yellow">Red Yellow</div>
                    <div class="yellow blue">Yellow Blue</div>
                    <div class="red green">Red Green</div>
                </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
        var classname = [];
        $( function () {

            $( '.check' ).change( function () {
                if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) ) {
                    // $( '.main div' ).css( 'display', 'none' );
                    
                    if((this).className){
                    classname.push((this).className.split(' ')[0].trim());
                    $( '.main div' ).each(function() {
                    $(this).css('display','none');
                    var block = this;
                    classname.forEach(function(value,index,array){
                    if(block.className.includes(value)){
                      $(block).css('display','block');
                      }
                    });
    });
                    

                    }

                }
                if ( $( this ).is( ':checked' ) == false ) {
                    classname.pop( ( this ).className );
                };
            } );
        } );
        $( '#clear' ).on( 'click', () => {
            $( '.check' ).prop( 'checked', false );
            classname.length = 0;
                      $( '.main div' ).each(function() {
                    
                  $(this).css('display','block');
                  
    });
        } );
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<div class="container grid">
                <div class="sidebar">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="green  check">Green
                    <input type="checkbox" class="blue check">Blue
                    <input type="checkbox" class="red check">Red
                    <input type="checkbox" class="yellow check">Yellow
                    <input type="button" value="Clear" id="clear">
                </div>
                <div class="main">
                    <div class="green yellow">Green Yellow</div>
                    <div class="blue red">Blue Red</div>
                    <div class="yellow">Yellow</div>
                    <div class="blue">Blue</div>
                    <div class="green ">Green</div>
                    <div class="green red">Green Red</div>
                    <div class="red yellow">Red Yellow</div>
                    <div class="yellow blue">Yellow Blue</div>
                    <div class="red green">Red Green</div>
                </div>
</div>
```

I have done some changes in your code.Check if this answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

I have minify and reduced possibility's of error

```
var classname = [];
$(function () {
    $('.check').change(function () {
        let CurrentObject = $(this);
        let Ischecked = CurrentObject.is(':checked');
        if (Ischecked) {
            if (CurrentObject.className) {
                classname.push(CurrentObject.className.split(' ')[0].trim());
                $('.main div').each(function (index, mainDiv) {
                    // mainDiv.css('display', 'none');   
                    $(mainDiv).hide();
                    classname.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
                        if (mainDiv.className.includes(value)) {
                            // $(mainDiv).css('display', 'block');
                            $(mainDiv).show();
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        }
        if (!Ischecked) {
            classname.pop(CurrentObject.className);
        };
    });
});

$('#clear').off('click').on('click', () => {
    $('.check').prop('checked', false);
    classname.length = 0;
    $('.main div').each(function (index,mainDiv) {
        // $(mainDiv).css('display', 'block');
        $(mainDiv).show();
    });
});
```